# Is my method of working fine?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-verification, uniform-distribution

> Suppose a point $X$ is selected at random from a line segment $AB$ of length $l$ and midpoint $O$. Find the probability that $AX,BX$ and $AO$ form a triangle.

My method and working is:

> Case 1: Let $AX<\dfrac{l}{2}$. Then it is obvious that $AX<AO<BX$ and $BX=l-AX$. Then $AX,AO,BX$ will form a triangle iff $AX+AO>BX$ implying $AX+\dfrac{l}{2}>l-AX$ i.e. $AX>\dfrac{l}{4}$. The probability of this event is $P(AX>\dfrac{l}{4},AX<\dfrac{l}{2})=\dfrac{1}{4}$
>
> Case 2: Let $AX>\dfrac{l}{2}$ then obviously $AX>AO>BX$ and we have $BX=l-AX$. Then $AX,AO,BX$ will be a triangle iff $AO+BX>AX$ i.e. $AX<\dfrac{3l}{4}$. The probability of this event is $P(AX<\dfrac{3l}{4},AX>\dfrac{l}{2})=\dfrac{1}{4}.$
>
> So the desired probability is $\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{4}=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

The reason I posted my solution is that I am having certain doubts. If the above is correct, what is wrong with $P(AX>\dfrac{l}{4}|AX<\dfrac{l}{2})P(AX<\dfrac{l}{2})$ in the first case? But this gives different answer. I actually do not know the correct answer. Same for the second case. Actually, I always get confused with conditional probabilities in the continuous case.

A comprehensive evaluation is desired.

Comment: "But this gives different answer." How so?

Comment: Because when I compute $P(AX>l/4|AX<l/2)$ I integrate $(1/l)dx$ from $l/4$ to $l/2$ and then I multiply this with $P(AX<l/2)=1/2$. So I am effectively getting the final answer $0.5$ times of what I wrote in the question, if I apply this method, isn't it?

Comment: If one integrates (1/l)dx from l/4 to l/2, one gets P(AX>l/4,AX<l/2), not P(AX>l/4|AX<l/2).

Comment: Why is that? This is the part where I get confused. It would be great if you can explain. Because given that $AX<l/2$, should it not be natural to consider $P(AX>l/4|AX<l/2)=\int_{l/4}^{l/2}dx/l$?

Comment: No. 1/l is the density of AX on (0,l) hence the integral of 1/l on every (Borel) B included in (0,l) yields P(AX in B). Please check the definitions.

Comment: Anyway I also figured that out by myself. So, is the solution correct?

Comment: See I have not studied Borel sets and all that but I realized that $P(AX>l/4|AX<l/2)$ is NOT the integral I was talking about. For a proof, consider $P(AX>x|AX<l/2)=P(x<AX<l/2)/P(AX<l/2)=(F(l/2)-F(x))/F(l/2)=\dfrac{\int_{x}^{l/2}(1/l)dx}{(1/2)}$ which easily proves you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right answer. Easier way to solve this is

Note that three line segments will be $\frac{l}{2}, \mathcal x, l-x$

For these to form a triangle, sum of two sides must be greater than the third.
So

$\frac{l}{2} + x > l - x$

Rearranging gives

$x > \frac{l}{4}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$

and $\frac{l}{2} + l -x > x$

Rearranging gives

$x < \frac{3l}{4}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$

and

$x + l-x > \frac{l}{2}$

$l > \frac{l}{2}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(3)$ which is obvious ;)

So triangle will be formed if

$\frac{l}{4} <x < \frac{3l}{4}$

The probability of this happening is $0.5$ because $X \sim  U(0, l)$

Try a different variant of this problem

You've a stick 10m long. You break it randomly at a point. Then you break the remaining stick randomly at a point again. Find the probability that the three pieces will form a triangle.

Comment: Thanks for the simplified approach!! And I shall be working on the variant and I will be posting my answer ASAP as a comment. You are a really cool alcohol :D